# Upload multiple archives in django model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

i'm using a django inline model to receive multiple images in a principal model, but i don't know how to add this data to my inline model in the views.py.

```
    class FoundPet(models.Model):
        
        TIPO_CHOICES = (
            ('C','Cachorro'),
            ('G','Gato')
        )
        GENDER_CHOICES = (
            ('M','Macho'),
            ('F','Fêmea')
        )
        # Nome do Responsável
        nome = models.CharField(max_length = 40, blank = True)
        # Telefone do responsável
        phone = models.CharField(max_length = 40, blank = True)
        # Descrição
        description = models.TextField()
        # Tipo do animal
        tipo = models.CharField(max_length = 1, choices = TIPO_CHOICES, blank = False, null = False)
        # Sexo do animal
        gender = models.CharField(max_length = 1, choices = GENDER_CHOICES, blank = False, null = False)
        active = models.BooleanField(default = False)
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, default=1)
        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.id)
        class Meta:
            db_table = 'found_pet'



    class ImagesFoundPet(models.Model):
        img = models.ImageField(upload_to = "media", null= True,blank = True)
        user = models.ForeignKey(FoundPet,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.id)
```

And i wrote a form html to receive the data from the user and send to my view.

```
def set_found_pet(request):
    # Nome de quem está cadastrando
    nome = request.POST.get('nome') 
    # Telefone do responsável
    phone = request.POST.get('phone')
    # Descrição
    description = request.POST.get('description')
    
    # Tipo do animal
    tipo = request.POST.get('tipo')
    # Sexo do animal
    sexo = request.POST.get('sexo')
    # Usuário
    user = request.user
    lost = LostPet.objects.create(description = description, phone = phone,photo = file, user=user, tipo=tipo, gender = sexo, nome=nome)

    # Reading the multiple data from the form user

    file = request.FILES.getlist('files')
    for f in file:

    return redirect('/')
```

The ask is cause i don't know how to add this data urls, from the images, to the inline model. I'm getting it in the admin page, so I think that the model is working well.